# Bash/shell script: syntax error in expression

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new shell scripting and have a quick question about my code.
This works:

```
x=2
y=4
z=6
x=$(( $x-1 ))
y=$(( $y-2 ))
z=$(( $z-3 ))
echo $x $y $z

$ script.sh
1 2 3
```

And this works:

```
n=2,4,6
IFS=$',' read x y z <<< $n
echo $x $y $z

$ script.sh
2 4 6
```

But this results in a syntax error:

```
n=2,4,6
IFS=$',' read x y z <<< $n
x=$(( $x-1 ))
y=$(( $y-2 ))
z=$(( $z-3 ))
echo $x $y $z

$ script.sh
syntax error in expression (error token is "4 6-1 ")
2 4 6 -2 -3
```

Could someone please explain why this doesn't work and what the syntax error means? Thanks!

Comment: Your code worked for me. You can find out a lot by using bash's debugging option (add `set -x` at the beginning of your file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem is not using quotes in `read` command.**

Use it as:

```
IFS=$',' read x y z <<< "$n"
```

When you use it without quotes as `IFS=$',' read x y z <<< $n` then only variable `x` gets value as: `2 4 6` but `y` and `z` remain empty hence next set of statements cause error.

Comment: This is actually a bug that was fixed in 4.3, as the `IFS` should only apply to the `read`, not the here-string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Qouting $n does make the 3rd code block work. But $n is unquoted in the 2nd code block and $x $y and $z get their values. Why is this?

Comment: Use your echo as `echo "[$x] [$y] [$z]"` to see what variables are populated after `$n` is unquoted.

Comment: [2 4 6] [] [] Ok, I get it now.